# How to correctly format 2 elements in the same grid area using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am dynamically generating elements and placing them in grid areas.

Each "cell" of grid elements live in a parent container, which has `display: contents` set, enabling the children to be placed on the grid individually.

This is for a booking application and each element on the grid will have a different `grid-row-end` depending on its duration.

All the elements in a "cell" parent have the same `grid-row-start`

However, when 2 elements begin at the same grid row, they overlap.

Is there any way to format these elements within the context of the grid-area ?

for example:

```html
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: [colHeader] 0.25fr [_Sunday] 1fr [_Monday] 1fr [_Tuesday] 1fr [_Wednesday] 1fr [_Thursday] 1fr [_Friday] 1fr [_Saturday] 1fr;   
grid-template-rows: [rowHeader] 0.5fr [_09-00] 1fr [_09-30] 1fr [_10-00] 1fr [_10-30] 1fr [_11-00] 1fr   [_11-30] 1fr [_12-00] 1fr [_12-30] 1fr [_13-00] 1fr [_13-30] 1fr [_14-00] 1fr [_14-30] 1fr [_15-00]        1fr [_15-30] 1fr [_16-00] 1fr [_16-30] 1fr [_17-00] 1fr [_17-30] 1fr;">
  
  <div class="cell" style="display: contents">
    <div style="grid-area: _16-00 / _Sunday / _17-00 / _Sunday;">
      activity 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="grid-area: _16-00 / _Sunday / _17-30 / _Sunday;">
      activity 2
    </div>
  </div> 
<div>
```

In this example, the 2 div.cell have the same grid-row-start but different grid-row-end attributes, and as such they overlap.

I understand that is this the expected behaviour, but is there a way to override this and force them to not overlap.

Comment: Do you have any visual reference, working code for better interpretation ?

Comment: I would not use `display:contents`(used for different purpose). Use the parents as grid placeholders and then use `display: flex` to align elements in their respective parent.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner I was originally doing this, but I cannot have 2 elements with different grid spans through this method.

Comment: What is this `app-grid` tag? Is it some framework you are using? This question wasn't tagged as such.

Comment: @elena yes it is from angular, however it is not relevant to the answer. they can be any element. I have changed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, there is not :) I would try to fix your generation function to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to prevent overlapping grid elements.

I ended up setting the margin-left and width of each element to be a fraction of the number of elements in the cell.

I half expected the answer to be no, but maybe there was something I was missing or any tricks/hacks.

Thanks for your help.